# Top align <td> in EDM template

Tags: html, css, email, inline

Hoping someone can help me with a small problem I'm having modifying the code for an email template.

The template contains `<td>`'s that when additional copy is added, they center align, but I can't work out how to get them to top align. Like I've shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Hoping someone can help explain the tweak I need to make. Thank you so much!

Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <title>EmailTemplate-Responsive</title>
    <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
    <!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->

    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style type="text/css">
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
      /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
html,  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
* {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
/* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table,  td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */
.yshortcuts a {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
/* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
}
</style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style type="text/css">

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #3eaeef !important;
            border-color: #3eaeef !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;

            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#e0e0e0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td><center style="width: 100%;">

            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
            <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;"> (Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body. </div>
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --> 

            <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center"><img src="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/NineLogo_2D.png" width="200" height="50" alt="Nine-Logo" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Header : END --> 

            <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">

            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td class="full-width-image"><img src="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/9Galaxy_New-TemplateHeader.jpg" width="600" alt="Jordan-Hooper" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END --> 

            <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 40px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"> 

                    <span style="color: #3697e9; font-size: 25px;"><strong>Nine Galaxy 101<br /></strong></span>
                    <br>
                    At Nine we have made TV buying easier with the most advanced buying platform, 9Galaxy. 2019 saw the launch of dynamic audience delivery across all screens, allowing media buyers to buy Nine’s linear TV and broadcast video on demand inventory in one simple transaction. 
                    Wavemaker’s Senior Client Manager, Jordan Hooper, speaks about the benefits of 9Galaxy, saying that it provides speed, accuracy and consistency for their clients, and delivers on audience and reach goals.
                    To learn more, click below. 
                    <br>
                    <br>

                <!-- Button : Begin -->

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="border-radius: 40px; background: #008fe1; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #008fe1; border: 15px solid #008fe1; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 30px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                      <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->View Video<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                      </a></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>

                <!-- Button : END --></td>
              </tr>


            <!-- Two Even Columns : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                            2020 promises to be a revolutionary year for television with the launch of VOZ or Virtual Australia, the new measurement platform coming in February next year. <br><br> Agencies and TV executives both see this new system giving clients a better understanding of how audiences are shifting and, while they may not be watching the traditional TV screen as much, they are still engaging with the content across multiple devices.<br><br> AdNews asked some of TV's senior executives for their predictions on what 2020 will look like. <br><br>Nine’s Richard Hunwick suggest “My call is that 2020 will be the year ‘Total Television’ comes into its own, as Brand returns to fashion and VOZ allows real and robust cross platform measurement between Linear TV and BVOD.<br><br>
                          Read more here.<br>
                          sdfasdfasdf asdfa sd asd fasdf
                            asd fasdf asdf asd fasd f
                            as dfasdf asdfasdfa</td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                            Australia’s favourite social experiment is returning to our screens in 2020 and the search for love will again captivate hearts and minds across the country. As we meet a new group of singles this ratings juggernaut promises to reach new heights, all in the name of love.<br><br> For the second year in a row Married at First Sight was Australia’s No. 1 non-sports program of 2019. MAFS securing a national linear broadcast average audience of 1.948 million viewers per episode (Metro: 1.457 million / Regional: 491,000). The finale attracted a national linear broadcast average audience of 2.798 million viewers (Metro: 2.110 million / Regional: 688,000).<br><br> For a sneak peek at our new MAFS couples, click here. <br><br>Married at First Sight returning to Channel 9 and 9Now in 2020.
 </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Two Even Columns : END --> 

            <!-- Three Even Columns : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Three Even Columns : END --> 

            <!-- Thumbnail Left, Text Right : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png"  width="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"><strong style="color:#111111;">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> <br>
                            <br>
                            Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <br>
                            <br>

                            <!-- Button : Begin -->

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                                  <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->A Button<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                                  </a></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>

                            <!-- Button : END --></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Thumbnail Left, Text Right : END --> 

            <!-- Thumbnail Right, Text Left : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td dir="rtl" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"><strong style="color:#111111;">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> <br>
                            <br>
                            Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <br>
                            <br>

                            <!-- Button : Begin -->

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                                  <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->A Button<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                                  </a></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>

                            <!-- Button : END --></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Thumbnail Right, Text Left : END -->

          </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END --> 

            <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                    <span class="mobile-link--footer"> Source: Text Here.</span> <br>
                <br>

                <a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #34a2fb;" href="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/" target="_blank">nineforbrands.com.au</a> <br/> <br/> This email was sent to: <%= recipient.email %> <br/> &nbsp; <br/> <%@ include view='UnsubscriptionLink' %>

                    </td>

              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Footer : END -->

          </center></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td.stack-column-center{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}


add this css to HTML (given)
```

Comment: Thank you both! That defiantly fixed the alignment issue. @And - The code is from an Adobe Dreamweaver responsive email template, so I assumed it would be good to tweak and go. I am now having another issue though. Despite finishing the template, and it looking/working as expected, the email is not getting through our EDM platform (adobe campaign classic) It's not showing any errors, but is simply not arriving in inboxes. Can anyone tell me if they see any obvious issues with the below?

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/0QG5oi7Y0U/files/fi-ad2f282d-58e3-48ca-981f-d2f158abca8a/fv-13fe8df5-5e3b-4f88-82b4-cbbfd73db889/9Galaxy_R2_V8.html

Answer (score 0):

G'day. You should use `display: inherit;`

Code below will help your problem;
Also I didin't understand why you using HTML table codes instead of bootstrap or div with class!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <title>EmailTemplate-Responsive</title>
    <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
    <!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->

    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style type="text/css">
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
      /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
html,  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
* {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
/* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table,  td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */
.yshortcuts a {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
/* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
}
</style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style type="text/css">

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #3eaeef !important;
            border-color: #3eaeef !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;

            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#e0e0e0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td><center style="width: 100%;">

            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
            <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;"> (Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body. </div>
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --> 

            <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center"><img src="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/NineLogo_2D.png" width="200" height="50" alt="Nine-Logo" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Header : END --> 

            <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">

            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td class="full-width-image"><img src="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/9Galaxy_New-TemplateHeader.jpg" width="600" alt="Jordan-Hooper" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END --> 

            <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 40px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"> 

                    <span style="color: #3697e9; font-size: 25px;"><strong>Nine Galaxy 101<br /></strong></span>
                    <br>
                    At Nine we have made TV buying easier with the most advanced buying platform, 9Galaxy. 2019 saw the launch of dynamic audience delivery across all screens, allowing media buyers to buy Nine’s linear TV and broadcast video on demand inventory in one simple transaction. 
                    Wavemaker’s Senior Client Manager, Jordan Hooper, speaks about the benefits of 9Galaxy, saying that it provides speed, accuracy and consistency for their clients, and delivers on audience and reach goals.
                    To learn more, click below. 
                    <br>
                    <br>

                <!-- Button : Begin -->

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="border-radius: 40px; background: #008fe1; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #008fe1; border: 15px solid #008fe1; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 30px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                      <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->View Video<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                      </a></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>

                <!-- Button : END --></td>
              </tr>


            <!-- Two Even Columns : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                            2020 promises to be a revolutionary year for television with the launch of VOZ or Virtual Australia, the new measurement platform coming in February next year. <br><br> Agencies and TV executives both see this new system giving clients a better understanding of how audiences are shifting and, while they may not be watching the traditional TV screen as much, they are still engaging with the content across multiple devices.<br><br> AdNews asked some of TV's senior executives for their predictions on what 2020 will look like. <br><br>Nine’s Richard Hunwick suggest “My call is that 2020 will be the year ‘Total Television’ comes into its own, as Brand returns to fashion and VOZ allows real and robust cross platform measurement between Linear TV and BVOD.<br><br>
                          Read more here.<br>
                          sdfasdfasdf asdfa sd asd fasdf
                            asd fasdf asdf asd fasd f
                            as dfasdf asdfasdfa</td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td class="stack-column-center"  style="display:inherit;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                            Australia’s favourite social experiment is returning to our screens in 2020 and the search for love will again captivate hearts and minds across the country. As we meet a new group of singles this ratings juggernaut promises to reach new heights, all in the name of love.<br><br> For the second year in a row Married at First Sight was Australia’s No. 1 non-sports program of 2019. MAFS securing a national linear broadcast average audience of 1.948 million viewers per episode (Metro: 1.457 million / Regional: 491,000). The finale attracted a national linear broadcast average audience of 2.798 million viewers (Metro: 2.110 million / Regional: 688,000).<br><br> For a sneak peek at our new MAFS couples, click here. <br><br>Married at First Sight returning to Channel 9 and 9Now in 2020.
 </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Two Even Columns : END --> 

            <!-- Three Even Columns : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_270x270.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid"></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Three Even Columns : END --> 

            <!-- Thumbnail Left, Text Right : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png"  width="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"><strong style="color:#111111;">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> <br>
                            <br>
                            Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <br>
                            <br>

                            <!-- Button : Begin -->

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                                  <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->A Button<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                                  </a></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>

                            <!-- Button : END --></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Thumbnail Left, Text Right : END --> 

            <!-- Thumbnail Right, Text Left : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td dir="rtl" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"><img src="../../2020/00 - Email Templates/1 - Dreamweaver Responsive/2 - Dreamweaver/images/Image_170x170.png" width="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"><strong style="color:#111111;">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> <br>
                            <br>
                            Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <br>
                            <br>

                            <!-- Button : Begin -->

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                                  <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->A Button<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                                  </a></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>

                            <!-- Button : END --></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Thumbnail Right, Text Left : END -->

          </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END --> 

            <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                    <span class="mobile-link--footer"> Source: Text Here.</span> <br>
                <br>

                <a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #34a2fb;" href="https://www.nineforbrands.com.au/" target="_blank">nineforbrands.com.au</a> <br/> <br/> This email was sent to: <%= recipient.email %> <br/> &nbsp; <br/> <%@ include view='UnsubscriptionLink' %>

                    </td>

              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Footer : END -->

          </center></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
html css email inline
shareeditflag
```